# How to add mediators in wso2am-4.1.0?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am using wso2am-4.1.0 and I am having trouble adding a simple in sequence and an out sequence as mediators while creating an API. In the previous versions the feature was readily available.
How can I simply add mediators while creating an API in wso2am-4.1.0?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In API Manager v4.1.0, it is done by adding Policies. The product provides a set of in-built policies to add to In-Sequence, Out-Sequence and Fault Flow.

Check the below for more details - https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/design/api-policies/attach-policy/

You can also create new custom policies and associate them - https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/design/api-policies/create-policy/